# Report Manager Permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, project-management

Is there any permission in Report Manager by which my manager can view the report definition i.e. can view the SQL Query but cannot edit it and save/publish it on the server?

I am using Report Builder 3 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: From the New Role Assignment page, it's look like the "Report Builder" role (described as "May view report definitions") does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you..

When you give a user an access to the report server you have to specify the permission he will get.

When you add new Role for a user you have a list of roles, the one which fits to your need named "Report Builder". This permission gives the user to view the report definitions.

It means that the user will be able to open the report with report builder but not save it back to the report server

See screenshot
[image]

Comment: I gave one user the "Report Builder" permissions but he was still able to edit,save and publish the reports.